# Problems extracting contourArea opencv (Python)

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am trying to obtain the biggest area in a image with OpenCV and Python, here the code:

```
#Loading image:
fuente=cv.LoadImage('train/fruit1.jpg')

#Converting to grayscale...
#Converting to binary...
#Apply canny method...
#Dilating borders...

#Trying obtain contours:
storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
contours = cv.FindContours(bordes, storage, cv.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,(0,0))

#Drawing Contours...
contornoimg=cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(fuente),fuente.depth,1)
cv.DrawContours(contornoimg,contours,cv.Scalar(255),cv.Scalar(0),2,1,8,(0,0));
cv.SaveImage("train/contornos.png",contornoimg);
```

If now I open the imagen "contornos.png", I can see differents contours, not only one, like I want the biggest contour, I have to calculate the contour with biggest area

```
max_area = -1
best_cnt = None

for cnt in contours:
    area = cv.ContourArea(cnt,slice=cv.CV_WHOLE_SEQ)
    if area > max_area:
        max_area = area
        best_cnt = cnt
```

But when I execute the file, obtain this error message:

```
cv.ContourArea(cnt,cv.CV_WHOLE_SEQ)->AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CV_WHOLE_SEQ'
```

Any help? Thank you for all!

Comment: It would be nice if you could upload the image you are using- makes it easier for us to test your code.  Additionally, you could make your life a lot easier by using the newer `cv2` interface for Python.  I switched recently, and it really is much more convenient.

Comment: It is forbidden uploading image by new users, I tried it, but I had to delete them, but don't worry finally yesterday I decided to change to cv2, I had a lot of problems with the old version so I had to change all my functions to cv2 and I can extract the areas without problems, thank you!

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score -1):

I use this one:

import cv2

area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

I found it here:
http://opencvpython.blogspot.ru/2012/04/contour-features.html

Comment: He's already using `cv.countourArea()`. Is there a difference with cv2?